# What wrong I have done? The function of GetDiskFreeSpaceExA didn't work at all

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I tried to use `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA` function, but it doesn't work:

```
int drvNbr = PathGetDriveNumber(db7zfolderw);

if (drvNbr == -1)   // fn returns -1 on error
{
    const char * errmsg = "error occured during get drive number";
    strcpy_s(retmsg, strlen(errmsg) + 1, errmsg);
    return -3;
}

char driverletter = (char)(65 + drvNbr);
string driverstr(1, driverletter);
driverstr = driverstr + ":";

PULARGE_INTEGER freespace = 0;
                PULARGE_INTEGER totalnumbtype = 0; 
                PULARGE_INTEGER totalnumberfreebyte = 0;


                    fileSize = SzArEx_GetFileSize(&db, i);
                    BOOL myresult=GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(
                        driverstr.c_str(),
                        freespace,
                        totalnumbtype,
                        totalnumberfreebyte
                        );
```

The value of variable `freespace` is `0`. I have no idea why it didn't work if the value of variable which is `driverstr.c_str()` was `D:`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: by fact this is clear *c/c++* question, not related to winapi/windows. you call some function `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(driverstr.c_str(), 0, 0, 0)` where first parameter is const pointer. and what you want after this ? how function can return to you any data ? *The value of variable freespace is 0*. because you yourself assign it to 0 `PULARGE_INTEGER freespace = 0;`

Comment: This question is beyond belief.

Comment: @RbMm I'm kind of new to C/C++,I'm a Java developer,i don't even know the pointer,so I'm sorry

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply pointers to variables that will hold the value returned. Right now you a re supplying null pointers so nothing is retured:

```
::ULARGE_INTEGER freespace{};
::ULARGE_INTEGER totalnumbtype{}; 
::ULARGE_INTEGER totalnumberfreebyte{};

::BOOL myresult
{
    ::GetDiskFreeSpaceExA
    (
        driverstr.c_str()
    ,   &freespace
    ,   &totalnumbtype
    ,   &totalnumberfreebyte
    )
};
```

It would also be a good idea to use wide char versions of these functions.

Comment: @fasdfdabsad You should access it like `freespace.QuadPart`. `(UInt64)&freespace` does not access stored value at all, it is a C-style cast of pointer to integer